# ERRO MYSQLI_FETCH_ARRAY

Tags: php

**Meu código :**

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['login'] = "";

    ?>
    <?php 

    //arquivo com as configuracoes de HOST, USUARIO, SENHA e BANCO
    require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../include/config.php';

    // Conectar ao banco de dados das prefeituras
    $db_selected_pref = mysqli_connect($HOST, $USUARIO, $SENHA,$BANCO); 
    //if (!$conectar_pref) { die('Não foi possível conectar: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); } 

    // Seleciona o banco de dados
    //$db_selected_pref = mysqli_select_db($conectar_pref, $BANCO);
    if (!$db_selected_pref) {die ('Não foi possível acessar a base: ' . mysqli_connect_error());}

    //SELEIONA O CODIGO DA EMPRESA

     if($_SESSION['login'] != "")
     {
      $NOME =$_SESSION['nome'];

      $sql_codigo_empresa = mysqli_query($db_selected_pref,"SELECT codigo, ultimanota FROM cadastro WHERE nome = '$NOME'");
      list($CODIGO_DA_EMPRESA,$ULTIMA_NOTA)=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_codigo_empresa);
     }

    // lista confguracoes
    $sql_configuracoes = mysqli_query($db_selected_pref,"
        SELECT 
            endereco, 
            cidade, 
            estado, 
            cnpj, 
            email, 
            secretaria, 
            lei, 
            decreto, 
            topo, 
            logo,
            brasao, 
            codlayout, 
            declaracoes_atrazadas, 
            gerar_guia_site 
        FROM  
            configuracoes
    ");
    list($CONF_ENDERECO, $CONF_CIDADE, $CONF_ESTADO, $CONF_CNPJ, $CONF_EMAIL, $CONF_SECRETARIA, $CONF_LEI, $CONF_DECRETO, $CONF_TOPO, $CONF_LOGO,$CONF_BRASAO, $CONF_CODLAYOUT,$DEC_ATRAZADAS,$GERAR_GUIA_SITE) = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_configuracoes);

    $sql_boleto_banco = mysqli_query($db_selected_pref,"
        SELECT bancos.boleto
        FROM boleto
        INNER JOIN bancos ON bancos.codigo = boleto.codbanco
        ");

    list($BOLETO_BANCO)=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_boleto_banco);
    ?>
```

**ERRO**:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\eiss\site\inc\conect.php on line 74
>       Call Stack
>       #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
>       1   0.0010  372272  {main}( )   ...\conect.php:0
>       2   0.0030  411144  mysqli_fetch_array ( )
>       ...\conect.php:74

Pessoal, não consigo resolver esse erro, o que to fazendo de errado???

Comment: cade sua query ? do msqli
esse erro diz que o que está sendo passado não é um mysqli resultado, e sim  um boolean 1 ou 0

Comment: coloca no  final da sua query mysqli_query um or die(mysqli_error()) ai exibir mais detalhes do erro

Comment: **Nota: a original indicada usa MYSQL em vez de MYSQLI, mas a solução é a mesma. Colocar um `or die( mysqli_error( $CONEXAO ) )` em cada linha**

Comment: Pessoal, tentei fazer como me foi dito, mas os erros continuam!!

Comment: Vocês podem me indicar em quais linhas devo inserir o código informado??